# Gravity Forms Find Sum of List Column

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, pdf-generation, gravity-forms-plugin

I am attempting to calculate the total sum of a list column in Gravity Forms, 
unfortunately this is not a feature that is included in the main plugin, so I have had to find a different source to accomplish this. I was able to find a script that is supposed to accomplish this, available here,
[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c0hjmo4w/)

```
function calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency) {
var columnTotal = 0,
    preField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId,
    totalField = jQuery('#input_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId),
    cellValue;
currency = (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined');
jQuery(columnClass).each(function () {
    cellValue = jQuery(this).val();
    cellValue = (currency) ? gformToNumber(cellValue) : cellValue;
    columnTotal += parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
});x
if (jQuery(preField).hasClass('gfield_price')) {
    columnTotal = gformFormatMoney(columnTotal);
    if (jQuery(preField + ' input').length > 1) {
        totalField.html(columnTotal);
        totalField = jQuery('input[name="input_' + totalFieldId + '.2"]');
    }
} else {
    columnTotal = (currency) ? gformFormatMoney(columnTotal) : columnTotal;
}
totalField.val(columnTotal).change();
gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId);
}
    function listFieldColumnTotal(formId, fieldId, column, totalFieldId,       currency) {
var listField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + fieldId,
    columnClass = '.gfield_list_' + fieldId + '_cell' + column + ' input';
jQuery(listField).on('blur', columnClass, function () {
    if (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined') {
        gformFormatPricingField(this);
    }
    calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency);
});
jQuery(listField).on('click', '.add_list_item', function () {
    jQuery(listField + ' .delete_list_item').removeProp('onclick');
});
jQuery(listField).on('click', '.delete_list_item', function () {
    gformDeleteListItem(this, 0);
    calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency);
});
}
 listFieldColumnTotal( 140, 1, 3, 3, true );
```

However, I am unsure of which elements I should be changing and which should be left as is. If anyone has experience with this, and can guide me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 2):

A little late here, but I stumbled across this script and decided to use it in order to create a user defined amount of price fields.  The client wished to be able to enter multiple invoice dollar amounts and display the total and I was able to get this working using the following method:

1. The magic with the script lies in the final line:

   ```
   listFieldColumnTotal( 140, 1, 3, 3, true );
   ```

The elements are described in the function, but are described in order as follows:

- The Form ID (ex. gform_wrapper_**6**)
- The list container's ID (ex. #field_6_**7**)
- The column item which we want to use as the dynamic value which lives beneath the list container (ex. .gfield_list_7_cell**2**)
- The id of the result input's container (ex. field_6_**18**)
- defines wether or not we're using a currency (I didn't experiment with this value set to "false", but I imagine it works the same

So, this will result in our final declaration will look like this:

```
    listFieldColumnTotal( 6, 7, 2, 18, true );
```

2. I used the gform_pre_render filter to attach the script to the form.  In order to do this, we integrate the above script into our functions.php file:

```html
    add_filter( 'gform_pre_render', 'realtimePriceListUpdate' );
 function realtimePriceListUpdate( $form ) {
 ?>

  <script type="text/javascript">

   jQuery(document).ready(function(){

    function calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency) {
        var columnTotal = 0,
            preField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId,
            totalField = jQuery('#input_' + formId + '_' + totalFieldId),
            cellValue;
        currency = (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined');
        jQuery(columnClass).each(function () {
            cellValue = jQuery(this).val();
            cellValue = (currency) ? gformToNumber(cellValue) : cellValue;
            columnTotal += parseFloat(cellValue) || 0;
        });
        if (jQuery(preField).hasClass('gfield_price')) {
            columnTotal = gformFormatMoney(columnTotal);
            if (jQuery(preField + ' input').length > 1) {
                totalField.html(columnTotal);
                totalField = jQuery('input[name="input_' + totalFieldId + '.2"]');

            }
        } else {
            columnTotal = (currency) ? gformFormatMoney(columnTotal) : columnTotal;
        }

     totalField.val(columnTotal);
        gformCalculateTotalPrice(formId);

    }

    function listFieldColumnTotal(formId, fieldId, column, totalFieldId, currency) {
        var listField = '#field_' + formId + '_' + fieldId,
            columnClass = '.gfield_list_' + fieldId + '_cell' + column + ' input';
        
        jQuery(listField).on('focusout', columnClass, function () {

            if (currency && typeof gf_global !== 'undefined') {
                gformFormatPricingField(this);
            }
            calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency);

        });

        jQuery(listField).on('click', '.add_list_item', function () {
            jQuery(listField + ' .delete_list_item').removeProp('onclick');
        });

        jQuery(listField).on('click', '.delete_list_item', function () {
            gformDeleteListItem(this, 0);
            calculateLFColumnTotal(formId, columnClass, totalFieldId, currency);
        });

    }

     listFieldColumnTotal( 6, 7, 2, 18, true );

   }); 

  </script>

  <?php

  return $form;

 }
```

3. Finally, we can't use the "total" field supplied by Gravity forms. We have to make a "Product" field and this is the field which we grab the id from in Step 1 (The id of the result input's container).  Also, we have to enable the "Allow field to be populated dynamically" option in the Advanced tab of the Product field. Optionally, we can change the product's Field Type to "hidden", since we don't want to display both the Total and a Product Field.
   [Here's a screenshot of the fields required for this list calculation script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TnHSm.png)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the [List Field Calculations](https://github.com/richardW8k/RWListFieldCalculations) plugin?

It extends the number field calculation options to include list field columns.

You can get the total of a column and the count of rows in a field and then configure your own calculations, e.g. 'sum of column 3'. The calculation will automatically populate the number field.

Comment: This plugin script facilitates the original request nicely. Just tested with Wordpress 5.4.1 and Gravity Forms Version 2.4.18